# Why changing css class order on tag make elements disappear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my HTML code.

Case 1:

```
<i class="csx-icons-select-hollow-active follow-handler"></i>
```

Case 2:

```
<i class="follow-handler csx-icons-select-hollow-active"></i>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.csx-icons-select-hollow-active {
    background-position: 0 -300px;
    display: inline-block !important;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 33px;

}
[class^="csx-icons-"] {
    background: url("../img/sprite.png") no-repeat scroll 100px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

**follow-handler** does not exist on my css file, only in my html inside `<i class="">`. It'd be the same thing as having `.follow-handler{}` on my css file.

Here is what happens in case 1:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/On2ia.png

And here is what happens in case 2:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX40I.png

As you can see, swapping the order of *follow-handler* and *csx-icons-select-hollow-active* is enough to make the icon disappear.

**Why is this a problem?**

When I use jQuery `$('.follow-handler').toggleClass('.csx-icons-select-hollow-active')` I'll end up with follow-handler BEFORE csx-icons* and this will make my icon disappear.

Does anyone knows why this happens? Why the order of a non-existent class is enough to make some elements vanish?

Comment: It's the "attribute starts with" selector, not the "class starts with" selector

Comment: The `^=` part of your second selector is the problem. `^=` is matching the *beginning* of the `class` string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> .csx-icons-select-hollow-active

Means *"Is a member of the class `csx-icons-select-hollow-active`* but

> [class^="csx-icons-"]

Means *"The string value of the class attribute starts with `csx-icons-"`*

If you swap the class order, then the class attribute no longer starts with those characters.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough, I was referring to changing the class order in the html TAG not in my css file.

Comment: @magroski — Yes, I know. Look at my answer again. "the class **attribute** starts with `csx-icons-`". Attributes are part of HTML, not CSS.

Comment: Oh, now i see! I'd totally forgot about ^ meaning "starts-with". Thanks for the quick answer and have a nice day :D

Answer (score 2):

The first one's classes "starts with" "csx-icons-" while the second one's classes doesnt "starts with" "csx-icons-".

Learn about this "starts with" in the [official w3 page](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings)